# VBA query - adapting existing code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've found a bit of VBA which is helping me do what I want to do, which includes the following:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TargetSh) 
NxtEmptyRw = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C2").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C3").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("G2").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("G3").Value 
End With 
End Sub
```

How would I adapt the line referring to `G2`, so that it returned the value under that of `C2`, rather than carrying on along the same row - effectively creating a two row by two column table, rather than a one row by four column table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer a shorter solution like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TargetSh) 
  NxtEmptyRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C2:C3,G2:G3").Copy
  .Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Dirk - is there any way I can twist this around to run down two columns, rather than run across two rows - in effect, transposing the data?

Comment: @DaveCoram the `True` after the `PasteSpecial` is for transposing... just change or skip it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C2").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C3").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("G2").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("G3").Value
```

with:

```
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C2").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("C3").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw + 1, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("G2").Value 
.Cells(NxtEmptyRw + 1, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSh).Range("G3").Value
```

Comment: Would there be an add-on to each line to only pick them up if there's data in them? - some of my rows may not have anything in them.